# how to properly define namespace in SOAP request?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am having a pre-complied class, which my input SOAP message should fit into.
The fields and order everything is correct, except for the namespace, I tried adding same namespace in @webservice as well as in input SOAP xmlns. 
Yet I am getting the following error.

[image]

my Service:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "OTMTransService",targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm/transmission/v6.4" )
public class OTMTransServiceImpl implements OTMTransService{
```

XML input I am hitting,

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:trm="http://receiver.tms.renault">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <trm:publish>
            <Transmission>
        <TransmissionHeader/>
        <TransmissionBody>...
    </TransmissionBody>
   </Transmission>
   </trm:publish>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Output I am getting,

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"TransmissionHeader"). Expected elements are &lt;{http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm/transmission/v6.4}TransmissionBody>,&lt;{http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm/transmission/v6.4}TransmissionHeader> </faultstring>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix TransmissionHeader and TransmissionBody with a namespace prefix and declare that prefix:

`In the top tag add: xmlns:ts="http://xmlsns.oracle.com/apps...the rest..."
then ...
<ts:TransmissionHeader>...
<ts:TransmissionBody>...`

If you paste your XML request as text I can show you more specifically